# Why do some fruits have their seeds disintegrated

Tags: fruit, seeds

Sometimes I'd come across a Lychee or a Naseberry whose seeds are kinda disintegrated.. in a thick powdered form, either completely or partially. What could cause such a thing? And is the fruit with such seed harmful?

I wish I had pics to show but it happens rarely.

Here's a normal Lychee with normal seed:

[image]

And what I sometimes find in place of the solid black seed is something that has the texture like this wet dirt:

[image]

but obviously more like the seed itself that has disintegrated into a thick wet powder.

Comment: Just a guess, but I would say that the process of the seed growing into a plant started. The fruit will still be eatable in most cases. We have a similar phenomenon with peaches where the inside of the hard core changes.